# Foreign keys SQL Server 2016 (msg 1769)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
use CollegeDB
create table [Majors]
(
    Major_name nvarchar(20) not null,
    Major_head_of_major nvarchar(20) not null,
    primary key (Major_name)
)

use CollegeDB
create table [Courses]
(
    Course_code nvarchar(10) not null,
    Course_name nvarchar(20) not null,
    primary key (Course_code),
    foreign key (Major_name) references Majors
)
```

And I'm getting this error:

> Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
>   Foreign key 'Major_name' references invalid column 'Major_name' in referencing table 'Courses'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 41
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

How can I solve it?
Thank you!

Comment: Major_name would have to exist in table Courses.

Comment: It looks like you are just referencing the table and not a column name.

Comment: Wrong Syntax.  Just google it, man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the second function to make sure you create the column in the second table that you want to set as your foreign key.

Try this.

```
create table Courses (
    Course_code nvarchar(10) not null,
    Course_name nvarchar(20) not null,
    Major_name nvarchar(20) not null,
    primary key (Course_code),
    foreign key (Major_name) references Majors(Major_name)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference Major_Name in Courses with Major_Name in Majors, you may need to add Major_Name column in Courses table and then create a foreign key constraint. Try following.

```
create table Courses
(
    Course_code nvarchar(10) not null,
    Course_name nvarchar(20) not null,
    Major_name nvarchar(20)
    primary key (Course_code),
    constraint fk_Courses_Major foreign key(Major_Name) references Majors(Major_name)
)
```