# FOREIGN KEY references invalid

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE MEDICO (
    DNIMedico CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    NumeroColegiado VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Nombre VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    FechaNacimiento DATE NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_MEDICO PRIMARY KEY (DNIMedico)
)

CREATE TABLE PACIENTE (
    DNIPaciente CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    Nombre VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Direccion VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    Edad INT NOT NULL,
    Peso FLOAT NOT NULL,
    Altura FLOAT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_PACIENTE PRIMARY KEY (DNIPaciente)
)

CREATE TABLE MEDICO_PACIENTE (
    CONSTRAINT fkMP_MEDICO FOREIGN KEY (DNIMedico) REFERENCES
    MEDICO (DNIMedico),
    CONSTRAINT fkMP_PACIENTE FOREIGN KEY (DNIPaciente) REFERENCES
    PACIENTE (DNIPaciente),
    Especialidad VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
)
```

> Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
>   Foreign key 'fkMP_MEDICO' references invalid column 'DNIMedico' in referencing table 'MEDICO_PACIENTE'.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 18
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: mysql <> sql-server. Please tag only the relevant database (the error message looks like sql-server).

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Foreign keys SQL Server 2016 (msg 1769)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41046504/foreign-keys-sql-server-2016-msg-1769)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a foreign key does not automagically create a column. You need to declare the column first, then the foreign key.

Hence:

```
CREATE TABLE MEDICO_PACIENTE (
    DNIMedico CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    DNIPaciente CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    Especialidad VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fkMP_MEDICO FOREIGN KEY (DNIMedico) REFERENCES MEDICO (DNIMedico),
    CONSTRAINT fkMP_PACIENTE FOREIGN KEY (DNIPaciente) REFERENCES PACIENTE (DNIPaciente)
);
```

Note that each refering columns should have the same datatype and length as the column they reference.

It would also be a good idea to declare a primary key for the `MEDICO_PACIENTE` table. Possibly, you want a compound primary key on `(DNIMedico, DNIPaciente )`:

```
CREATE TABLE MEDICO_PACIENTE (
    DNIMedico CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    DNIPaciente CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    Especialidad VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fkMP_MEDICO FOREIGN KEY (DNIMedico) REFERENCES MEDICO (DNIMedico),
    CONSTRAINT fkMP_PACIENTE FOREIGN KEY (DNIPaciente) REFERENCES PACIENTE (DNIPaciente),
    CONSTRAINT pk_MEDICO_PACIENTE  PRIMARY KEY (DNIMedico, DNIPaciente)
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4891efbc6522808c7bb2d4511ed750d1)**

Comment: Thank you, I had not noticed